# Regular Expression in R: Variable Number of Characters

Tags: r, regex

I want to locate all instances in a character vector that follow this pattern: `A-B-.CDE`, where '-' represents either one or two numeric characters, i.e. 0 to 9. I intend to use grep, with v as my character vector.
So, when `v = c("A1B2.CDE", "A3B45.CDE", "AB.CDE", "XY.CDE")`, I want grep to return `c(1, 2)`.

What regular expression can I use for pattern in grep to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-`, we can use digits (`\\d+` - matches one or more digits).  The `.` is a metacharacter to match any character, so we can escape (`\\`) to evaluate literally

```
grep('^A\\d+B\\d+\\.CDE', v)
#[1] 1 2
```

Here, the pattern matched is 'A' from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), then letter 'B', one or more digits (`\\d+`), the dot (`.`) and letters 'CDE'

If there is only 1 or 2 digits, replace the `\\d+` with `\\d{1,2}` i.e.

```
grep('^A\\d{1,2}B\\d{1,2}\\.CDE', v)
#[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be

```
v <- c("A1B2.CDE", "A3B45.CDE", "AB.CDE", "XY.CDE")
grepl("^A\\d{1,2}B\\d{1,2}\\.CDE", v)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had more reputation points I would include this as a comment instead of an answer, but the poster asked for "-" to represent one or two digits. Using the "+" allows any number of the preceding token (in this case \\d) to match; therefore the string "A333B45.CDE" would erroneously be returned as a match.

Replace the "+" with "{1,2}" to achieve the desired result.